# Python : IndexError: list index out of range (Unable to locate error)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a student who just started learning Python and I just can't seem to fix this error which keeps popping up. I've been at it for hours with no avail, so I'd love some input from the experts.

The program idea is simple, just a program which can calculate the costs of all the components needed to build a computer.

Code:

```
import datetime

Comp =  [["Processor",["P3", "P5", "P7"],[100, 120, 200],[10, 10, 10],[0,0,0]], #Component - Choices - Price - Stock - Total of each component sold.
        ["RAM",["16GB", "32GB"],[75,150],[10, 10],[0,0]],
        ["Storage",["1TB", "2TB"],[50,100], [10, 10],[0,0]],
        ["Screen",["19", "23"],[65, 120], [10, 10],[0,0]],
        ["Case",["MT", "IT"],[40,70], [10,10],[0,0]],
        ["USB",["2", "4"],[10, 20], [10, 10]],[0,0]]


cList = []  #List of updating items.
cPrice = [] #List of updating prices.
fullPrice = [] #After order is complete, total price is added to this array for final day stats.

orderNo = 1 #Order number counter.
time = datetime.datetime.now()  #Datetime counter.


print ("Welcome to Build Your PC! \n\nSelect the components below to estimate the final price for the product!\n")

def Pick():
    print ("Order Number #",orderNo) #Print order number.

    for i in range (6): #Repeat 6 times each for all the Components.

        print ("\nPlease choose an available", Comp[i][0],"component from the list below.")
        print ("Component: Price:")
        for x,y in zip(Comp[i][1], Comp[i][2]): #Zips the two lists (Component + Price) together to format the two lists side by side.
            print ("{:10} $".format(x) ,y) #Format variable to add padding between lists.

        choice = input("\nEnter here : ").upper() #Force lowercase to fit with array variables.
        if choice in Comp[i][1]:    #Validation if chosen Component is in list.
            cIndex = Comp[i][1].index(choice)   #Indexes chosen Component location for future reference.
            cList.append(choice)             #Adds chosen Component to cList list (Line 9).
            cPrice.append(Comp[i][2][cIndex])   #Adds chosen Component to cPrice list (Line 10).

            if Comp[i][3][cIndex] > 0:  #Validation if item is in stock.
                Comp[i][3][cIndex] = (Comp[i][3][cIndex] - 1)   #Minus 1 to current stock.
                print ("Item is in stock. Now", Comp[i][3][cIndex], "is left in stock.")

                tPrice = sum(cPrice)    #Sums up total price of all the items in the shopping cart.
                print ("Total cost in shopping cart is $", tPrice,".")

                Comp[i][4][cIndex] = (Comp[i][4][cIndex] + 1)   #Adds plus 1 to Total of each component sold.

            else :
                print ("Item is out of stock!")
                Pick()

        else :
            print ("Invalid entry.")
            Pick()

    print ("\nOrder received. Calculating final details...")

    print ("\nOrder Number #", orderNo, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
    print ("Shopping cart :")
    for x,y in zip(cList, cPrice):  #Print two lists in two columns with list of components and prices.
        print ("{:4} $".format(x), y)

    print ("Final price + 20% taxes : $", (tPrice*1.2))
    print ("Thank you for shopping at Build Your PC!")

Pick()
rOrder = input("\nDo you wish to add another order? Y or N?").upper()   #Repeat order.
if rOrder == ("Y"):
    orderNo = (orderNo + 1) #Counts number of orders.
    fullPrice.append(tPrice)    #Adding total price variables per build for final earnings.
    cList = []
    cPrice = [] #Resetting both arrays for next order.
    Pick()

else :
    print ("\nTotal orders made today : #", orderNo)
    print ("Total earnings today : $", sum(fullPrice))  #Adding up all variables array for final earnings.

    print ("Component: Amount Sold:")
    for i in range(6):                              #Repeats 6 times to print component amounts sold for each section.
        for x,y in zip(Comp[i][1], Comp[i][4]):     #Zips two lists (Choice + Total Sold) to display side by side.
            print ("{:4}".format(x) ,y)

    print ("Closing Build Your PC program...")
```

Log :

```
Welcome to Build Your PC! 

Select the components below to estimate the final price for the product!

Order Number # 1

Please choose an available Processor component from the list below.
Component: Price:
P3         $ 100
P5         $ 120
P7         $ 200

Enter here : P3
Item is in stock. Now 9 is left in stock.
Total cost in shopping cart is $ 100 .

Please choose an available RAM component from the list below.
Component: Price:
16GB       $ 75
32GB       $ 150

Enter here : 16GB
Item is in stock. Now 9 is left in stock.
Total cost in shopping cart is $ 175 .

Please choose an available Storage component from the list below.
Component: Price:
1TB        $ 50
2TB        $ 100

Enter here : 1TB
Item is in stock. Now 9 is left in stock.
Total cost in shopping cart is $ 225 .

Please choose an available Screen component from the list below.
Component: Price:
19         $ 65
23         $ 120

Enter here : 19
Item is in stock. Now 9 is left in stock.
Total cost in shopping cart is $ 290 .

Please choose an available Case component from the list below.
Component: Price:
MT         $ 40
IT         $ 70

Enter here : MT
Item is in stock. Now 9 is left in stock.
Total cost in shopping cart is $ 330 .

Please choose an available USB component from the list below.
Component: Price:
2          $ 10
4          $ 20

Enter here : 2
Item is in stock. Now 9 is left in stock.
Total cost in shopping cart is $ 340 .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Computer v2.py", line 64, in <module>
    Pick()
  File "Computer v2.py", line 44, in Pick
    Comp[i][4][cIndex] = (Comp[i][4][cIndex] + 1)   #Adds plus 1 to Total of each component sold.
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The error on line 44 giving me this - IndexError: list index out of range

It's really perplexing. The fact is, it runs 5 times before on the 6th run, it just stops working? There is nothing wrong with the snippet itself as I have tested it in its own environment, but for some reason it just breaks down on the 6th run for component USB.

Thank you for taking your time to help me. I'm still in my learning stages, so any additional suggestions to improve this program unrelated to this specific bug will also be appreciated!

Comment: Post your code and error (traceback) in your question with proper formatting please. Don't make it harder for people to help you.

Comment: @MooingRawr I believe I formatted it now? Or did you mean something else? Apologies, I'm quite new to posting on this site.

Comment: your mistake is here `["USB",["2", "4"],[10, 20], [10, 10]],[0,0]]` you have an extra `]` change it to `["USB",["2", "4"],[10, 20], [10, 10],[0,0]]]`

Comment: python is usually very convenient to avoid this kind of bugs and you should not loose time with this. At least, for your 'Comp' list, you could use a dictionary instead of a list. That is the principle of python: you loose a factor of several tens on the CPU time, but you save developer time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small typo:

```
["USB",["2", "4"],[10, 20], [10, 10]],[0,0]]
```

Should be:

```
["USB",["2", "4"],[10, 20], [10, 10],[0,0]]]
```

This is causing your 6th entry in the list to be cut short thus not incluing the `[0,0]` in the fourth slot of the list.

---

Also on Line 69, `tPrice` isn't defined in the scope (it's defined in the function scope but outside of the function the variable isn't created, perhaps you want to return `tPrice` from the function and assign it to the function call:

```
    #previous code that I didn't include
    print ("Thank you for shopping at Build Your PC!")
    return tPrice

tPrice = Pick()
rOrder = input("\nDo you wish to add another order? Y or N?").upper()   #Repeat order.
if rOrder == ("Y"):
    orderNo = (orderNo + 1) #Counts number of orders.
    fullPrice.append(tPrice)    #Adding total price variables per build for final earnings.
    cList = []
    cPrice = [] #Resetting both arrays for next order.
    Pick()
#rest of the code I didn't include
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Just a quick question, it seems after assigning tPrice to the function call I have lost the looping functionality. I run the code once, complete Order#1, then I say yes to repeat and complete Order#2. However after that, the program just ends, I do not quite get the option to choose an Order#3. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: You never had a loop, encase that `Y` check in a while loop and break out when they say `N`

Answer (score 1):

Your list has an error so that the last sublist is too short: ["USB",["2", "4"],[10, 20], [10, 10]],[0,0]] should be ["USB",["2", "4"],[10, 20], [10, 10],[0,0]]].

Debug printouts are useful, that's how I found it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the initial data that is set in the `Comp` array. One of the square brackets is in the wrong place, causing the `USB` array to be closed early.

The problem is at the end of the USB array:

```
Comp =  [["Processor",["P3", "P5", "P7"],[100, 120, 200],[10, 10, 10],[0,0,0]], #Component - Choices - Price - Stock - Total of each component sold.
    ["RAM",["16GB", "32GB"],[75,150],[10, 10],[0,0]],
    ["Storage",["1TB", "2TB"],[50,100], [10, 10],[0,0]],
    ["Screen",["19", "23"],[65, 120], [10, 10],[0,0]],
    ["Case",["MT", "IT"],[40,70], [10,10],[0,0]],
    ["USB",["2", "4"],[10, 20], [10, 10]],[0,0]]
```

There is a `]` after `[10,10]` that should be after the `[0, 0]]` section instead.

To fix this error, update the `Comp` array to this:

```
Comp =  [["Processor",["P3", "P5", "P7"],[100, 120, 200],[10, 10, 10],[0,0,0]], #Component - Choices - Price - Stock - Total of each component sold.
    ["RAM",["16GB", "32GB"],[75,150],[10, 10],[0,0]],
    ["Storage",["1TB", "2TB"],[50,100], [10, 10],[0,0]],
    ["Screen",["19", "23"],[65, 120], [10, 10],[0,0]],
    ["Case",["MT", "IT"],[40,70], [10,10],[0,0]],
    ["USB",["2", "4"],[10, 20], [10, 10],[0,0]]]
```